# Accept payments to subaddresses without local node

Tags: python

First of all as you might guess I'm working on a tip bot for Monero subreddit. It is more like a personal project to learn about python bots and monero integration.

My question, I cannot find a way to connect to a monero remote node using python to scan incoming transactions to a subaddress. Could anyone point me to the right direction? I've only found dead monero repositories for this and cannot find a solution with main monero python github repo.

Note: I don't want to run my node nor download the blockchain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find a way to connect to a monero remote node using python to scan incoming transactions to a subaddress.

Run `monero-wallet-rpc` (which you can connect to a remote node), then use its JSON RPC method [incoming_transfers](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#incoming_transfers).

> I've only found dead monero repositories for this...

If you don't know how to call a JSON RPC directly in python, use one of the wrapper libraries. Both [monero-ecosystem/monero-python](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-python) and [utils/python-rpc](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/utils/python-rpc) are both up-to-date.